# Dataframe groupby sort (categorical variable)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

```
In [167]:
    df

Out[167]:
    Gender  University
0   Male    A
1   Female  B
2   Male    C
3   Male    D
4   Male    E
5   Female  A
6   Female  B
7   Female  C
8   Female  D
9   Female  E

In [168]:
df.groupby(['University','Gender'])['Gender'].size().unstack('Gender').fillna(0)

Out[168]:
```

[image]

Now, I would like to sort by Female and Male from highest to lowest so that when I bar plot, It'll be in a descending order. I tried many ways but to no avail.

In my last attempt I tried:

```
df.groupby(['University','Gender'])['Gender'].size().unstack('Gender').fillna(0).sort_values(ascending=False)

TypeError: sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `by=['Female', 'Male']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by one or another column:

```
print (df)
   Gender University
0    Male          A
1  Female          B
3    Male          D
4    Male          E
5  Female          A
2    Male          C
3    Male          D
4    Male          E
5  Female          A
6  Female          B
7  Female          C
8  Female          D
4    Male          E
5  Female          A
6  Female          B
3    Male          D
4    Male          E
5  Female          A
7  Female          C
8  Female          D
9  Female          E
```

```
df1 = df.groupby(['University','Gender'])['Gender']
        .size()
        .unstack('Gender', fill_value=0)
        .sort_values(by='Female', ascending=False)

print (df1)
Gender      Female  Male
University              
A                4     1
B                3     0
C                2     1
D                2     3
E                1     4

df1.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph1]

```
df2 = df.groupby(['University','Gender'])['Gender']
        .size()
        .unstack('Gender', fill_value=0)
        .sort_values(by='Male', ascending=False)
print (df2)
Gender      Female  Male
University              
E                1     4
D                2     3
A                4     1
C                2     1
B                3     0

df2.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph2]

If sort by both columns sorting of second column sort only duplicates (`D`, `C` columns):

```
df3 = df.groupby(['University','Gender'])['Gender']
        .size()
        .unstack('Gender', fill_value=0)
        .sort_values(by=['Female', 'Male'], ascending=False)
print (df3)

df3.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you! If I'd like to sort by the number of people from a university regardless of gender (from highest to lowest). How can I do that?

Comment: I dont understand, what is difference with my answer? Can you explain more?